# Content do not appear in iframe until i use the edit button in firebug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

Its getting me crazy in FF. I tried the same page in Chrome and content appears instantly.

I have an iframe that is loading a chart from another page.

The problem is that the chart do not appears until I inspect the element and click on the edit element button. Once I add space after the src property in the html code (see below for better understanding) the graph will be displayed instantly.

Graph using is of [jqPlot](http://www.jqPlot.com)

Before

```
<iframe src="http://localhost:4501/mainpage/graph.aspx"></iframe>
```

After

```
<iframe src="http://localhost:4501/mainpage/graph.aspx" ></iframe>
```

Image here.

[alt text http://img294.imageshack.us/img294/252/crazything.jpg](http://img294.imageshack.us/img294/252/crazything.jpg)

Comment: Are you sure this is not a firebug issue? I've seen other occasions where firebug being enabled causes iframe content not to be loaded/displayed for a long time. Check by completely disabling firebug and retest.

Comment: Tried it but still not avail...

Comment: Adding a space shouldn't affect anything. Could you set up a test page somewhere that we can look at? Would make it much easier to help.

Comment: Are you sure you tried by completely disabling the Firebug extension via Firefox options? I've had similar (ie. completely strange) problems simple because firebug is installed.

Answer (score 2):

```
<iframe src="#" onload="this.src='http://localhost:4501/mainpage/graph.aspx'">No Ifrmae allowed</iframe>
```

i am not sure why it does that could be a something from your computer ... but give this a go.
btw if you get the "no iframe allowed" could be that your ff has disabled iframe. sience you have mentioned that it shows the frame but there is a loading problem... then do check on your firebug... on the NET tab "http://localhost:4501/mainpage/graph.aspx" has been loaded successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're loading them from the same domain, you can access that iframe's js and DOM.

Add some space or and empty <span> to the dom in the iframe window via javascript to force a redraw.

Comment: The reason the iframe is displayed properly after you're editing it with FB is just that: you are forcing a redraw. Firefox is like that sometimes, but we still love it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to reload the frame manually (I mean, to see what happens)? (Right click it → This Frame → Reload Frame)